# Google Classroom - Get Folder ID for Course

Tags: php, string, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-classroom

I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to retrieve the Google Drive folder associated with a particular Course (ID).

My understanding is that this value is available as the teacherFolder value:

See Here:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses

```
"id": string,
"name": string,
"section": string,
"descriptionHeading": string,
"description": string,
"room": string,
"ownerId": string,
"creationTime": string,
"updateTime": string,
"enrollmentCode": string,
"courseState": enum(CourseState),
"alternateLink": string,
"teacherGroupEmail": string,
"courseGroupEmail": string,
"teacherFolder": {
  object(DriveFolder)
},
```

But this is returned as an object that contains:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "title": string,
  "alternateLink": string,
}
```

I am trying to get the Google Drive folder associated with the course in Google Classroom (by Course ID) so that I can upload a resource to the appropriate folder.

Please point me in the right direction.

(I am hoping to accomplish this via php.)

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses):

**Resource: Course**

```
{
"id": string,
"name": string,
"section": string,
"descriptionHeading": string,
"description": string,
"room": string,
"ownerId": string,
"creationTime": string,
"updateTime": string,
"enrollmentCode": string,
"courseState": enum(CourseState),
"alternateLink": string,
"teacherGroupEmail": string,
"courseGroupEmail": string,
"teacherFolder": {
object(DriveFolder)
},
"courseMaterialSets": [
{
object(CourseMaterialSet)
}
],
"guardiansEnabled": boolean,
}
```

You can check out the `CourseMaterialSet` property which hold all related marterials to the course.

#### CourseMaterialSet

> A set of materials that appears on the "About" page of the course. These materials might include a syllabus, schedule, or other background information relating to the course as a whole.

```
{
"title": string,
"materials": [
{
object(CourseMaterial)
}
],
}
```

#### CourseMaterial

> A material attached to a course as part of a material set.

```
{

// Union field material can be only one of the following:
"driveFile": {
object(DriveFile)
},
"youTubeVideo": {
object(YouTubeVideo)
},
"link": {
object(Link)
},
"form": {
object(Form)
},
// End of list of possible types for union field material.
}
```

Hope this helps.